# PHP - CSV header displayed twice in first page of pagination

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and trying to display the CSV data in a tabular format in my web page with pagination option. This is the code I have so far.

```
<?php
$names = file('demo.csv');
$page = $_GET['page'];
$pagedResults = new Paginated($names, 20, $page);
echo "<table border='2' bgcolor='#fbd998' style='float:center; margin:20'>";
//when $row is false loop terminates
while ( $row = $pagedResults->fetchPagedRow())
{
    echo "<tr><td>";
    $row1 = str_replace( ',', "</td><td>", $row );
    echo $row1;
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
//important to set the strategy to be used before a call to fetchPagedNavigation
$pagedResults->setLayout(new DoubleBarLayout());
echo $pagedResults->fetchPagedNavigation();
?>
```

The problem was, I was not able to display the CSV header information except the first page. To avoid this, I used the handler to extract the first line alone from CSV file (which contains the header information). I added the below piece of code before the while loop.

```
if (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE)
{
}
echo "<table border='2' bgcolor='#fbd998' style='float:center; margin:20'>";
echo '<tr><th>'.implode('</th><th>', $data).'</th></tr>';
```

This strategy seems to be working fine in all the pages except that in the first page, I have the CSV header twice. For example, my current first page looks like below.

- Column1 Column2 Column3
- Column1 Column2 Column3

  ---
- Rest of my data

  ---

Can someone please guide me on how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that csv doesn't distinguish header from actual data, so the first page starts from the first row in the file and outputs it. You have to either start reading data from row nr. 2, or stop showing header at page nr. 1.

Try changing

```
echo "<table border='2' bgcolor='#fbd998' style='float:center; margin:20'>";
echo '<tr><th>'.implode('</th><th>', $data).'</th></tr>';
```

to this:

```
if ($page != 1){
  echo "<table border='2' bgcolor='#fbd998' style='float:center; margin:20'>";
  echo '<tr><th>'.implode('</th><th>', $data).'</th></tr>';
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions. If I come back to first page after visiting some other pages, the contents of the first page are not displayed in the tabular format.

Comment: So the first time it displays everything OK, and the second time there  is no tabular format?

Comment: Even in the first time actually the header is displayed twice.

Comment: Maybe in your pagination class first page is 0, and not 1?